# jQuery highlightTextarea script won't work with variable as parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, object, highlight

I have a list of spam words in an PHP array that gets checked against user input. If there are any matches the matching spam words are send to jQuery highlightTextarea script (http://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/jquery-highlighttextarea/) from my PHP validation script via AJAX. This jQuery-script is supposed to highlight any of these spam words in the input textarea, so the user can directly see what's wrong. For this purpose the script has an option "words:" that accepts your own list of spam words in the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $("textarea").highlightTextarea({
        words: ["spam1","spam2", "..."]
    });
```

It works when I enter the words directly as seen in the code above, but I want to pass the array (or a string or whatever) with all the spam words from my AJAX request as parameter to that function. I have tried this:

```
$.each(msg.errors,function(k,v){
    if (k!='trash') {...} 
    else {trash = '["' + v.join('","') +'"]'}
});             
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").highlightTextarea({
    words: trash
});
```

The corrosponding words in textarea field get marked alright, but so do all other text passages that contain any of the letters used by the detected spam words. When I alert the string (or object??) `alert(trash);` I get `["spam1","spam2"]`. So I figured I could simply append 'trash' as parameter in the form: `words: trash`
 and this would be the same as: `words: ["spam1","spam2", "..."]` Obviously not. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're passing a string, not an array. Try building an actual array (maybe with `[]` and `push()`, maybe with `map()`, as you see fit).

Comment: you can use ,  $("textarea").highlightTextarea('setWords', [ 'array val','array val' ]);

Comment: @BharathRallapalli I have tried `$(document).ready(function() {
            $("textarea").highlightTextarea('words', [ "spam1","spam2" ]);
        });  ` just to see if it works, but unfortunately it does not. It seems the script excpects its parameters in the form `words: ["spam1","spam2", "..."]` ?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, @BharathRallapalli Thanks you guys. I simply had to do it like this: `$(document).ready(function() {
            $("textarea").highlightTextarea({words: v});
        }); ` It was there all along, just did not see it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, make sure your ajax request in jquery is returning json information, for me the issue was that my object looked like this, making sure my post response was json fixed this issue for me, but here's a demo of what i was seeing.

```
{
   words: "["blue","red","white"]"
}
```

when it should have looked like this

```
{
   words: ["blue","red","white"]
}
```